# Laravel how to return single column value using Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use the data from the SQL Query, to explain it further here is my code:

```
    $myquery = DB::table('attendances')->select('user_id')->where('date_only', '=', $newdate)->orderBy('logon','asc')->get();

    $myquery->user_id;
```

Now I want the value of my $myquery to be USER_ID's value, I get error if I used the Above code -$myquery->user_id;

Comment: I think it's because you're not retrieving a single result. so, if you want the user_id, you can iterate over $myquery, or select the first result )`->first()`

Comment: As @GiuServ said :
get() will return an array of attendance objects even if there is only one object matched the where conditions. 

Where first() will return the first matched object from the result. Even more than one object is matched where conditions.

Answer (score 40):

#### EDIT: As of version *5.1* `pluck` is deprecated, since *5.2* its meaning is completely different (as `lists` used to be), so use `value` method instead.

---

You're trying to get property of the array, so obviously you're getting error.

If you need single field only, then use `pluck` (which returns single value - string by default):

```
// let's assume user_id is 5

DB::table('attendances')
  ->where('date_only', '=', $newdate)
  ->orderBy('logon','asc')
  ->pluck('user_id');  // "5"
```

When you need whole row, then `first` (which returns stdObject):

```
$att = DB::table('attendances')
  ->where('date_only', '=', $newdate)
  ->orderBy('logon','asc')
  ->first();

$att->user_id; // "5"
$att->any_other_column;
```

And `get` is when you want multiple results (which returns simple array of stdObjects):

```
$result = DB::table('attendances')
  ->where('date_only', '=', $newdate)
  ->orderBy('logon','asc')
  ->get();

$result; // array(0 => stdObject {..}, 1 => stdObject {..}, ...)
$result[0]->user_id; // "5"
```

Comment: Where did you read that pluck is deprecated in 5.1? Is `value()` the alternative?

Comment: @GiuServ **Use the source, Luke!** https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1368-L1381 And yes, `value` is the new `pluck`

Comment: Nevermind, i just understand that **pluck** function as changed from 5.1.  I started directly from 5.3 and didn't get that previously it didn't had the same behaviour!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

**Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table**
`$email = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->value('email');`

**Retrieving A List Of Column Values**
`$titles = DB::table('roles')->pluck('title');`

Answer (score 26):

That's for Laravel 5.3:

```
$user_id = DB::table('attendances')->select('user_id')->where('date_only', '=', $newdate)->orderBy('logon','asc')->value('user_id');
```

Comment: `select('user_id')` isn't needed

Comment: It works but if no rows found you'll get an exception "Call value() on null"

Comment: @fdehanne - that's not entirely accurate. Although you might think it's redundant, getting into a good habit of ONLY selecting what you need from the database will make your application more performant, as less data is required for your query responses. As your grab grows, that data transfer gets quite large, and takes longer to transfer and process to your app servers.

So it's a very good idea to only select what you need.

Answer (score 11):

To get only the list of value of a single column you can do like this.

```
$result = CustomerInfo::select('eventDate')->pluck('eventDate');
```

here $result will give you the result like this:

```
["2019-03-25","2020-03-31","2019-03-31","2019-04-24","2019-11-26"]
```

hope it may help someone

Comment: thanks , it was actually what I was looking for

Answer (score 9):

This will return user_id only

```
$myquery = DB::table('attendances')->where('date_only', $newdate)->select('user_id')->pluck('user_id')->first();
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [latest documentation: 5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects%20documentation:%205.6)

```
DB::table('users')->select('name');
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion; but I am using Laravel 5.3 and pluck and value function is not deprecated as depicted above.

For more clarification:
**pluck()** will be used instead of **get()** when you want all the values only
**value()** will be used instead of **first()** when you want only one value.

use method **all()** to get the array of itmes. 
usage:

```
\App\User::whereIn('mobile',['971700000', '965000000'])->select('id')->pluck('id')->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

DB::table('yourtablename')->where('id', '=', $id)->orderBy('id','asc')->pluck('user_id')->toArray();

Comment: This simply repeats code from other answers. Please don't do that.

Comment: @Chris Actually this answer different, The point is toArray method.

Comment: @Parsa, that's not meaningfully different in the context of the question being asked.

Answer (score -2):

`DB::table('table_name')->select('column_name');`

Comment: Should explain your answer

Answer (score -2):

If you have data in array already and you want to filter only such kind of data, you can do this as well

````
  0 => "first_name"
  1 => "middle_name"
]


$users_data = User::where('id', '1')->get($filter_data );
return $users_data; ```

<pre> In laravel 5.4 works perfect for me </pre>
````

Answer (score -3):

```
 $myquery = DB::table('attendances')->select('user_id')
            ->where('date_only', '=', $newdate)->orderBy('logon','asc')->get();
```

by default, the returned data will be array of objects. you need to loop over it.

e.g.

```
foreach($myquery as $i)
{
    echo $i->user_id;
}
```