# Cannot convert an associative array to a complete collection in Laravel by using the collect() function

Tags: laravel, collections

I am working on building a money inventory web app with Laravel.

I have organized the tables in `users`where a user may have many `accounts`, which is a many-to-many relationship through the `account_user` table. For each account there're records for `transactions`. An account has many transactions.

In the `transactions` table I store the bill and the quantity. So, the *transactions* table has the following columns:

- account_id
- bill_id
- datetime
- transaction_number
- quantity

Inside the `bills` table, the *name* column refers to the bill denomination, that is to say, a 20 bill => like $20 USD bill, and so on.

In the `AccountController@show`, what I'm doing is the folowing:

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        $account = Account::findOrFail($id);
        //Get the transactions IDs
        $transaction_numbers = $account->transactions->map(function ($item,$key){
            //dump($item->id);
            return $item->transaction_number;
        });
        //$transaction_numbers = [1,2,3, ...];
        $transaction_numbers = $transaction_numbers->unique()->flatten();

        $balances=$transaction_numbers->map(function ($item,$key){           
            $total = Transaction::with('bill')->where('transaction_number',$item)->get()->reduce(function ($total, $item) {
                return $total + ($item->bill->name * $item->quantity);
            });
            //echo 'Tot: '.$total.'. Transaction ID: '.$item.'<br>';
            //THE PROBLEM COMES HERE
            return ['transaction_number'=>$item,'balance'=>$total];
        });

        //Now I want to add the date to the array and collection
$balances_array = $balances->toArray();
        $balances_tmp=[];
        foreach ($balances_array as $key=>$balance){
            //https://stackoverflow.com/a/46939910/1883256
            $date_time=DB::table('transactions')->where('transaction_number',$balance['transaction_number'])->take(1)->select('date_time')->pluck('date_time')->first();
            $balance['date_time']=$date_time;
            dump($balance);
            $balances_tmp[]=collect(['transaction_number'=>$balance['transaction_number'],'balance'=>$balance['balance'],'date_time'=>$date_time]);
        }
        //dd($balances_tmp);

        $balances = collect($balances_tmp);

        dd($balances);

        return view('accounts.account_show',[
            'account' => $account,
            'balances' => $balances,
        ]);
    }
```

Now when I try in the view to iterate and display the data in a table, like so:

```
...
@foreach($balances as $balance)
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>{{ $balance->transaction_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $balance->balance }}</td>
                @endforeach
...
```

I get the following error:

> Property [transaction_number] does not exist on this collection instance.

**Problem**
My problem is that, when I apply the collect function to the array, it does not actually convert everything to a collection, there're still remaining of an array! I show you the resulting dump:

```
Collection {#336 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Collection {#276 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▼
        "transaction_id" => "1"
        "balance" => 122220
        "date" => "2019-07-02 19:52:22"
      ]
    }
    1 => Collection {#373 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▼
        "transaction_id" => "2"
        "balance" => 155350
        "date" => "2019-07-02 20:24:44"
      ]
    }
    2 => Collection {#272 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▼
        "transaction_id" => "3"
        "balance" => 113980
        "date" => "2019-07-02 20:27:25"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you see, there're still arrays inside the collection and that's why I'm still getting that error

I am currently [reading this post of a forum](https://gist.github.com/brunogaspar/154fb2f99a7f83003ef35fd4b5655935) that may relate to my problem.

What am I missing then?

Comment: Where did you dump `$balances`?  IE in show(), or on the blade page?  Also - I probably missed it, but where are you actually setting that variable in the show() method?

Comment: I can't find your $balances variable in the controller

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, I have just added the line where I `dd($balances)` inside the `AccountController` just before returning the view

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have changed collection as array. in your blade also you can debug like this

```
@foreach($balances as $balance)
{{dd($balance)}}
@endforeach
```

then i hope you have to use it like below

```
 <td>{{ $balance['transaction_number'] }}</td>
```

Comment: I don't know how to return a collection from inside the `map()` function ... or maybe should I use the `each()` function instead?. I made edits to the controller to better explain. My bad.

Comment: have you finished ? my recommendation is don't call    queries many times in one function you have calling trans table so many times ??

Comment: You are right. I will redesign the database schema, so that it does not force me to query many times.